# RegisterClassObjects() Doesn't Find Classes To Register

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, com, atl, visual-c++-6

I'm in the process of converting an application from Visual Studio C++ 6.0 to Visual Studio 2008 and am running into problems with ATL.

I've been having a whole host of issues, but this is the first call that differs in return values between the two different compilers.

The following line, when compiled with VC++ 6.0, returns S-OK.  When running in VS 2008, it returns S-FALSE.  According to the MSDN documentation, this means it couldn't find any classes to register.

```
_Module.RegisterClassObjects(CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: That method belongs to ATL. ATL is shipped as full sources. You can just press "Step into" and investigate the problem.

Comment: Yea, I've been doing that, but not much has come from it.

I've been stepping through the VC++6.0 compiled version and comparing the functions called/return values to that of the VS2008.  The functions and parameters are mostly the same, but I haven't been able to figure out how to call the new functions with the parameters that are needed.

At this point, I've resolved myself to being stuck in the bowels of COM for a long time... ::sigh::

Answer (score 1):

I too ran into an issue related to `RegisterClassObjects` returning `S_FALSE` unexpectedly.  In my scenario, the service state was not changing from *Starting* to *Running* in a legacy C++/ATL/COM project.  `RegisterClassObjects` was returning `S_FALSE` (effectively a warning message) because:

- the previous developer had enabled COM (`_ATL_NO_COM_SUPPORT` had **not** been defined)
- no COM objects had been defined within the `*.EXE`

**CALL STACK**

- line 8192: `*ppEntry` was always NULL
- `AtlComModuleRegisterClassObjects`
- `CAltExeModule.RegisterClassObjects`
- `CAtlServiceModuleT.PreMessageLoop`

  - if `RegisterClassObjects` did not return `S_OK`, then the the service state was not updated to *Running*

**NEXT STEPS**

The options available to you will depend on your situation.  Why is `RegisterClassObjects` being called?  Why are no COM objects being detected?

In my case:

1. I could not prevent `RegisterClassObjects` from being called
2. I did not want to disable COM by introducing the `_ATL_NO_COM_SUPPORT` because I did not fully understand the repercussions of making such a change on an application I knew nothing about
3. I did not want to modify the SDK by replacing `if (FAILED(hr))` with `if (SUCCEEDED(hr))`

So I ensured that `AtlComModuleRegisterClassObjects` was able to find a valid COM object in the auto map (which is referenced by `pComModule->m_ppAutoObjMapFirst`)

**CONTEXT**

- Visual Studio 2013
- Windows SDK 7.1A
- Active Template Library version 12.00

**REFERENCES**

Given that I know little about COM & ATL, I found this statement to be a real eye opener:

> ATL Services are designed to serve COM objects. You failed to provide
>   any objects in the object map. Technically, ATL is working even better
>   - it detects there are no objects to serve, so there's no point in starting the service at all... The fault is yours - for using ATL in
>   an unsupported way. This said however, it's very simple to remove the
>   function call registering the objects...
>
> [SOURCE: [ATL Services and 2003]](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.vc.atl/_GmoPo27enc/q-F_6gE2-akJ)

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? Indeed you are supposed to override `PreMessageLoop` so that server with no ATL COM servers started.